# How to achieve parallel processing to improve processing time

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

Presently i am using springbatch to process csv and excel files in below manner.

1. Reader(will parse csv/excel files and male pojo)
2. Processor (will hit Db whether this record is there in DB or not )
3. Writer(will push the pojo to message queue)

In real time i have 50k + records to process for which my code almost taking 25 minutes. I want to improve processing time by implementing parallel processing(so that in parallel we can process the same in less time).

But i have no clue how to achieve parallel processing with Spring Batch. Can any one guide me how to do it or any suggestions to improve processing time.

```
@Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("CSV-Async-batch");
    }


    @Bean(name="csvjob")
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,ItemReader<List<CSVPojo>> itemReader,ItemProcessor<List<CSVPojo>,CsvWrapperPojo> itemProcessor,AmqpItemWriter<CsvWrapperPojo> itemWriter){
        Step step=stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-CSV").<List<CSVPojo>,CsvWrapperPojo>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(40)
                .build();



        Job csvJob= jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step).build();
```

====Reader for SynchronizedItemStreamReader=================

```
@Component
public class Reader extends SynchronizedItemStreamReader<List<CSVPojo>> {

    public static MultipartFile reqFile=null;
    List<CSVPojo> result = new ArrayList<CSVPojo>();

    @Autowired
    private CSVProcessService csvProcessService;

    public static boolean batchJobState ;

    /*public Reader(MultipartFile file){

        this.reqFile=file;
    }*/

    public void setDelegate(ItemStreamReader<List<CSVPojo>> delegate){

        /*try {
            this.read();
        } catch (UnexpectedInputException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NonTransientResourceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }


    @Override
    public List<CSVPojo> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
            ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!batchJobState){
        result=csvProcessService.processCSVFile(reqFile);
        System.out.println("in batch job reader");
        batchJobState=true;
        return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the partitioning technique to partition input files and process them in parallel. This is explained in details in the [Partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) section of the reference documentation.

You can also look at the [Local partitioning sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample) and the [Remote partitioning sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample) in the `spring-batch-samples` module.

There are similar questions to this one, I'm adding them here for reference:

- [Spring batch- Parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473976/spring-batch-parallel-processing)
- [Best Spring batch scaling strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107607/best-spring-batch-scaling-strategy)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnks, the above links are helpful. I have used Multi-threaded Step approach. Added my configuration code in above main thread. Here i have 2 records in csv file , it seems multiple threads acted on same file asynchronously and all the threads read and published to queue so i saw 24 records published(instead of 2). Is there any way i can read the file by multiple threads in synchronous way ?

Comment: I mean how we can make Batch job reader Thread safe? so that the read on file have to happen in Synchronized manner.

Comment: [`SynchronizedItemStreamReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Getting the error:  Error creating bean with name 'reader' defined in URL , Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A delegate item reader is required. I have to override public void setDelegate() in my reader? Please see the reader related code in above thread.

Comment: No, you don't need to override `setDelegate`, you need to set the delegate reader in the synchromized one. Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReaderTests.java#L92-L94